# react - ensure css loaded before iframe renders

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, webpack, preact

Dealing with a flash of unstyled content issue. I've got a chat widget that is injected onto users' pages. So that I don't clash with existing styles. I'm rendering in an iframe using `react-frame-component`. This works pretty nicely, but one problem I have is with the CSS.

`react-frame-component` accepts a prop `head` that you can use to pass a link to a stylesheet. Using MiniCSSExtractPlugin, I am able to get my css into a separate file that I can then link to:

```
render(props, state) {
  return (
    <Frame 
      head={<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />}
      scrolling="no"
    >
      <ChatWidget />
    </Frame>
  );
}
```

With this, I get the dreaded flash of unstyled content. I think it's because everything including `<ChatWidget>` renders before the css can be fully downloaded.

Is there a way I can ensure the CSS is downloaded before everything renders?

Also, not sure if it matters, but I'm using Preact.

Comment: For the sake of speed, I wouldn't do that. Try preloading the CSS from the main document using https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Preloading_content or inline the needed css in your framed component.

Comment: Did u manage to solve it?

Comment: yes - just posted an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up writing my own iframe component, using some tips from `react-frame-component` but writing it in a way I could be sure I had control over how it rendered. Here's what my iframe component looks like (note this uses Preact, which has some minor differences from React - it would be very easy to replicate this in React):

```
import {h, Component, createRef} from 'preact';
import {createPortal} from 'preact/compat';
import {cssLink} from '../utilities';

export default class Frame extends Component {
  iframeNode = createRef();
  iframeTest = document.createElement('iframe');

  static initialContent() {
    return `<!DOCTYPE html><head><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="${cssLink}"></head><body></body></html>`;
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.iframeNode.addEventListener('load', this.handleLoad);
  }

  handleLoad = () => {
    this.iframeRoot = this.iframeNode.contentDocument.body;
    this.forceUpdate();
  };

  sourceProp() {
    const canUseSrcDoc = 'srcdoc' in this.iframeTest;

    if (canUseSrcDoc) {
      return {
        srcdoc: Frame.initialContent(),
      };
    }

    // inserting Frame.initialContent() as the src is a hack for older browsers
    // to allow inserting our stylesheet before the children render, preventing
    // flashes of unstyled content
    return {
      src: `javascript: '${Frame.initialContent()}'`,
    };
  }

  render(props) {
    const {children, ...rest} = props;

    return (
      <iframe
        {...rest}
        {...this.sourceProp()}
        ref={ref => (this.iframeNode = ref)}
      >
        {this.iframeRoot && createPortal(children, this.iframeRoot)}
      </iframe>
    );
  }
}
```